# A little confused with this python dictionary example

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
data = [{'name':'Albert','rel':'Head','unique_number': 101},
        {'name':'Sheen','rel':'Head','unique_number': 201},
        {'name':'Peter','rel':'Son','unique_number': 101},
        {'name':'Chloe','rel':'Daughter','unique_number': 101}]
```

can you help me out in getting data like this? filtered on unique_number

```
updated_data = [
                 {'house_head':'Albert','members':['Peter','Chloe']},
                 {'house_head':'Sheen','members':[]}
            ]
```

Comment: Create a dictionary whose keys are the `unique_number` values. You can then fill this in with dictionaries with the appropriate `house_head` and `members` as you loop over `data`.

Comment: I've tried separating these house heads and members

`house_head = filter(lambda x: x['rel'] == 'Head', data)
members = filter(lambda x: x['rel'] != 'Head', data)`

Comment: That's one way to start. Then you can loop through the heads and create all the dictionaries, then loop through the members and add them to the `members` elements of the appropriate dictionary.

Comment: Can you have a family with only members, no head?

Comment: If so, filtering the data is probably not worthwhile. Just loop through the data and create the dictionary the first time you encounter the unique number, whether it's a head or a member.

Comment: no, Head is required but members can be null

Comment: can you suggest me any website where I can practice more problems related to dictionaries?

Comment: @rav yes, a great start is CodingBat - https://codingbat.com/python, which offers similar exercises to solve and also checks your solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
numbers=set([i['unique_number'] for i in data])
dict={i:{'Head':'', 'members':[]} for i in numbers}
for i in data:
    if i['rel']=='Head':
        dict[i['unique_number']]['Head']=i['name']
    else:
        dict[i['unique_number']]['members'].append(i['name'])
new_data=[{'house_head':dict[i]['Head'], 'members':dict[i]['members']} for i in dict]
```